# Why does a python regex only work with capturing brackets?

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I am writing a python function to process multi-line SQL statements.

e.g.

```
multi_stmt = """
-- delete empty responses
DELETE FROM idlongDVR_responses WHERE new_response_code = '';
DELETE FROM idwideDVR_responses WHERE new_response_code = '';

-- create a current responses table for idlongDVR
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS idlongDVR_respCurr;
CREATE  TABLE idlongDVR_respCurr
    SELECT *, MAX(modifiedat) AS latest  FROM idlongDVR_responses
    GROUP BY sitecode, id, dass, tass, field, value, validation_message
    ORDER BY sitecode, id, dass, tass; """
```

So I have written a regular expression to identify a newline if it is not followed by a double hyphen (start comment), and ends in a semi-colon

```
sql_line = re.compile(r"""
            \n+         # starting from a new line sequence
            (?!(--|\n)) # if not followed by a comment start "--" or newline 

            (.*?)       # <<<<< WHY ARE THESE CAPTURING BRACKETS NEEDED?

            ;           # ending with a semicolon
                      """, re.DOTALL|re.VERBOSE|re.MULTILINE)

stmts = sql_line.findall(multi_statement)

for stmt in stmts:
    stmt = stmt[1]
    if len(stmt) > 0:
        cursor.execute(stmt)
```

It works OK but only if I enclose the `.*?` term in brackets so it becomes `(.*?)`.  If I don't then I don't match anything.

Why is this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code around the line where you use sql_line for matching?

Comment: @Dmitry: Posted as edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"These capturing brackets are needed" because you used a capturing bracket inside the negative lookahead.

```
(?!(--|\n))
   ^     ^
```

Since this should never be matched, the first capturing group will always be empty in a successful match. Since some methods like `.findall` will only return capturing groups (if they exist), you'll only see a list of empty strings.

Removing the `(`...`)` here should make the regex behave as you expect. BTW you could use `[^;]*`  instead of `.*?`.

```
sql_line = re.compile(r"\n+(?!--|\n)[^;]*;")
```

Comment: I like the [^;] suggestion thought it took a minute for my head to compute. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using `findall`, aren't you?  `findall` is weird.  If you have any capturing groups in the regex, it returns *only* the contents of the capturing groups.  As @KennyTM pointed out, you have a capturing group inside your lookahead, and since it's a *negative* lookahead, your overall match succeeds only when the group fails to capture anything.  Thus, your list of empty strings.

Don't bother asking me why those empty groups *don't* show up when you use the brackets around the `.*?`.  From reading the docs, I would expect it to return a list of tuples consisting of two groups: one empty, and one the match you were expecting.  But I only get the non-empty groups.  That seems to be another layer of nonsensicalness to `findall` that I haven't encountered before.

By the way, you don't need the `MULTILINE` flag.  All that does is change the behavior of the anchors, `^` and `$`, allowing them to match at line boundaries as well as at the beginning and end of the whole string.  Maybe you knew that already, but there's a very persistent rogue meme floating around that goes "If it's multiline, you have to use `MULTILINE`", and I try to stamp on it whenever I see it.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I had included the brackets because I thought they were necessary for alternation - I guess not. Didn't know about the multi-line thing. Thanks both for your time answering this. First question on Stackoverflow. Amazed by the speedy response. Thanks

Comment: @drstevok: Even in the case grouping is needed, you could use `(?:`...`)` instead of `(`...`)` to avoid capturing.